# How to check pixel color with Pyglet?

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm using Pyglet and trying to print the background color of the current position of the mouse. The script that launch the application is the following:

```
import pyglet

from pyglet.window import Window
from background import Background


window = Window(fullscreen=True)

game_batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

r = Background(batch=game_batch)

@window.event
def on_mouse_motion(x,y, dx, dy):
    print(x,y) # print current position
    #### ... but how to print pixel color (RGB) here? ####

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    game_batch.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyglet.app.run()
```

The class `Background.py` is:

```
import pyglet

from physical_object import PhysicalObject

pyglet.resource.path = ['./resources']
pyglet.resource.reindex()

my_img = pyglet.resource.image('background.png')


class Background(PhysicalObject):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(img=my_img, *args, **kwargs)
```

Checking the docs, I've seen that OpenGL can be used to extract this color information, but I'm  confused about how. Should I use OpenGL? Or there is a simpler way to access pixel color?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can take a look at this:
[Setting individual pixels in Pyglet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962328/setting-individual-pixels-in-pyglet)

But in general, img.get_image_data() always returns all the pixels.
Here's the documentation to this: https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/image/#pyglet.image.AbstractImage.get_image_data

With the ImageData object you can then use 'set_data' or 'get_data' to retrieve or set pixels.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried [the solution proposed by Hyalunar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70768713/9893379) just adding the following method to class `Background`, which is called in every mouse motion event:

```
def check_position(self, x, y):
    img_data = road_img.get_region(x, y, 1, 1).get_image_data()
    width = img_data.width
    data = img_data.get_data('RGB', 3 * width)
    print(data[0] + ', ' + data[1] + ', ' + data[2])
```

And that solution works perfect!